# How do I solve a least square regression equation (see description)?

Tags: regression, least-squares

[image: See link above to see the equation, no idea why it doesn't display the image.]

For instance, how do I solve this for Delta13Cleaf = -23? The plusminus signs dont represent standard error, because for a given Delta13Cleaf, multiple values (or an interval, not sure) for MAP are computed. The author furthermore doesn't give a much more information than this, but another clue is that he gives three calculated MAPs: Mininum, maximum, and mean, with the mean not being the mean of the minimum and maximum value.

If someone would explain how to solve this, that would be great.

Source equation: Amiot et al, Environment and ecology of East Asian dinosaurs during the Early Cretaceous inferred from stable oxygen and carbon isotopes in apatite (2015)

Comment: How does the equation you give relate to a regression model and its least square solution?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Are you referring to the equation on the picture or on my a, b, c, d example?

Comment: @whuber what is unclear about this question?

Comment: The equations you write have no apparent connection to the contents of the image; nothing is explained; no background or context is given.  There isn't anything to be "solved."

Comment: @whuber I just gave an example on how to I thought normally to deal with the plusminus stuff. Anyway, i deleted it. Thanks for the correction and making the image visible.

Comment: Thank you.  Still, there is nothing to "solve" here: this is announcing the result of fitting a line to data pairs of the form $(\Delta^{13}C_\text{leaf},\log(\text{MAP}))$. The "$\pm$" are probably some kind of standard errors or confidence intervals for the coefficients that should be explained somewhere in the paper: their meaning cannot be determined just from this excerpt.

Comment: @whuber He doesnt mention anything like that unfortunately. He does, however, calculate a mean, max, and min MAP, that's all I know, and this mean is not calculated als the average of the min of max. So that seems very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Read it like this:

(0.082 +/- 0.0102) * delta13C + (1.3726 +/- 0.1875)

In other words, to calculate the mean you/I only need to do:

0.082 * delta13C + 1.3726